# column of second page swithches to first page

Tags: parcolumns

I am working on a document using `\begin{paracol}{4}`. For the columne break I use `\switchcolumn`

My problem starts on the second page: When I want to switch the column the text appears ad the page before if the space is not completely full with text (take a lof at the picture). What Could I do?

[image: switch to page 1]

```
% page setup
\documentclass[]{article}
\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{courier} % fonts
\usepackage{lmodern} % fonds
\usepackage{braket} % brakets



% geometry
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\geometry{headsep=\baselineskip}

% headers and footers
\usepackage{fancyheadings}

% graphics
\usepackage{graphicx} % interface for optional arguments
\usepackage{subfigure} 
\usepackage{xypic} %  variety of graphs and diagrams
\usepackage{float}


% colums / paragraphs
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{parskip} % paragraph layouts




% color
\usepackage[dvipsnames, table,x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage[singlespacing]{setspace}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % Seitenzahl mitte
\rfoot{Seite \thepage} % Seitenzahl rechts 
\rhead{Cheat sheet klinische Chemie} % Kopfzeile rechts oben
\lhead{} % Kopfzeile links oben 
\fancyheadoffset{0.01 cm}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\vspace{0.2cm}
\newgeometry{top=0.55in,bottom=0.55in,right=0.3in,left=0.3in} 
\begin{paracol}{4}

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would not use paracol for such a cheat sheet but either multicols or just simple minipages.